# Parsing XML files

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse the external xml file using this code with php and `simplexml_load_file();`
the problem it shows `$xml->title` as empty, it doesn't have any value,
althoug the XML file is loaded,

you can see it in this link 
http://abone.doganburda.com/test/indexNew.php

```
<?
    $file = 'http://doganburda.com.tr/Files/sonhaber.xml';
    if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file))
        exit('Failed to open '.$file);

    $description = $xml2;
    echo "Title: " .$xml->title. "<br />" .
        "Description: " .$xml->description. "<br />"         
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you var_dump the `xml` file?

Comment: it prints this string: "object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) {   ["@attributes"]=>   array(1) {     ["version"]=>     string(3) "2.0"   }   ["channel"]=>   object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {     ["item"]=>     object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (6) {       ["category"]=>       string(12) "YENÄ° DERGÄ°"       ["image"]=>       string(93) "http://doganburda.com.tr/Files/Haberler/DetayResim/29-04-2014-10-37-50VEGGIELIFE_KAPAKdty.jpg"       ["title"]=>       string(19) "VEGGIE LIFE Ã‡IKTI!"       ["description"]=>       string(120) "Vejetaryen  ve yaÅŸam tarzÄ±na uygun dergi  Veggie Life Ã§Ä±ktÄ±! " }   } }"

Comment: Look at Shankar Damodaran's answer should work

Comment: it worked as Shankar sais

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing them wrongly..

It should be

```
echo $xml->channel->item->title;
echo $xml->channel->item->description;
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Nczuxw)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
echo $xml->channel->item->title;
```